# Install and share Canon Lide 110 on the network

Tags: networking, share, canon, scanner

I'd like to setup my Canon Lide 110 and share it on the network so it's visible on the network and is available as a scanner. We have some Mac's on the network so ideally the scanner should be visible to these machines as well.

Comment: please can you clarify - which sharing scanner sharing options have you tried in this community wiki? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a tested clean answer to collect your bounty but the following bread crumbs might help you get where you want be. Your fist problem will be to get this scanner to work with Ubuntu. Some past LiDE scanners weren't sane compatible and won't work. Follow these instructions for the 210 and I believe your LiDE 110 will with Ubuntu, at least comments in the thread indicate so http://www.bottomlesspit.org/2010/12/23/canon-lide-210-scanner-support-on-ubuntu-1010-maverick. As to sharing your scanner between Ubuntu and Mac the following forum post may be get you started http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1007177.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your LiDE 110 will work without issue on Ubuntu, as SANE [says it is supported](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-CANON).

Instructions on sharing the scanner are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo#server).

Instructions and packages for accessing it via the Mac are [here](http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/).

An overview of the process is [here](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2006/10/09/1152/).